# Docker push fails when a file with whitespace in its name is included in the Docker image

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I'm having problems with a custom Docker image in which there are some files having some whitespaces in their names. When I execute the `docker push` command I have this error:

```
$> docker push example.azurecr.io/myimage
The push refers to repository [example.azurecr.io/myimage]
ecaa33aa3064: Pushing [==================================================>]     59MB/59MB
3f06df57be30: Pushing [==================================================>]  21.31MB/21.31MB
ca31a9af4714: Layer already exists
09eb78ab1afc: Layer already exists
62386d2295bd: Layer already exists
f7afe9869eba: Layer already exists
e2eb06d8af82: Layer already exists
svm.runProcess: command cat /tmp/d2/app/wwwroot/fonts/FranziskaWeb W03 BlackItalic.ttf failed with exit code 1
```

I run the Docker engine on Windows Server 2019 with the Linux containers feature enabled.

Unfortunately I'm not able to write a Dockerfile that reproduces this error.

[Someone](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-getting-svm-runprocess-failure/60538) [else](http://saka.docsio.net/58238841/cant-push-docker-image-to-azure-repository) on the Internet got this same error but I found no solution. As far as you know, does Docker have any problem with pushing images containing files with whitespaces?

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Is the problem as simple as the path needing to be quoted? e.g. `cat "/tmp/d2/app/wwwroot/fonts/FranziskaWeb W03 BlackItalic.ttf"`.

Comment: cat command is build-in to LCOW source code, and just used for printing the path of the error source.

Comment: @BenWhaley I cannot share the Dockerfile, sorry

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using the latest version, there is chance to update and fix it. It has been a problem, based on the comment on the [code.](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/69f9c8c90662290f3e3abc01a3be51b95b80367b/daemon/graphdriver/lcow/lcow.go#L1113)

It seems to be [fixed on 2019 February](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/2c8522b0a3ccaea946cc459ec650625235c8f4ad#diff-bc278ab32c245c096c6cee5d46cba8e6dad6e79363716582f8fdc096c855ecdd).

If you have already the latest version or you can't update it, then I fear that you are out of luck if you can't modify these specific files to not contain the whitespaces.

`svm.runProcess` seems to be part of [LCOW](https://github.com/linuxkit/lcow) image support, which is experimental and deprecated. See multiple pull-requests [which removed this feature recently](https://github.com/moby/moby/pulls?q=lcow), and the [initial one](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/42170). Containers in Windows space are moving towards WSL2, however it also seems like, that now (July 2021) they are moving away from WSL support on Windows Servers, based on the [GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6301#issuecomment-858816891):

"The Windows Desktop SKUs (where WSL 2 is supported) are recommended SKUs for these scenarios. For those who would like to use Linux in production scenarios in a server environment we recommend using server products such as Hyper-V VMs, and AKS on Azure Stack HCI. As always, we welcome any further Windows Server feedback through our Feedback Hub."

There is bigger issue explaining about the WSL 2 on Windows Servers, available on [here.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/678)

Comment: Thanks @Niklas. So I only have to enable WSL2 to overcome this problem automatically?

Comment: It seems like that that in recent Windows Server 2019 builds WSL2 is not functional anymore... https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/678

Comment: I updated my answer, seems like WSL 2 is getting removed from Windows Servers.

Comment: It's a huge pity that I will not be able to push my images on WIndows Server 2019